# awk: transpose column header to first field of row

Tags: awk, transpose

My input looks like this:

```
A|B|C
1|2|3
4|5|6
```

Using awk, I am trying to get:

```
A|1
B|2
C|3
A|4
B|5
C|6
```

My code:

```
gawk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
NR==1{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
        x_i=$i
    }
}
NR>1{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
        print x_i FS $i
    }
}' input
```

But it keeps only the last iteration of the `NR==1` block even if I use the same loop in `NR>1` bock:

```
C|1
C|2
C|3
C|4
C|5
C|6
```

Any trick?

#### EDIT

Thanks to Jose, I needed to change `x_i` by `x[i]`.

What about if using the same input, I would need to output:

```
A;B;C|1|2|3
A;B;C|4|5|6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
     NR==1{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) d[i]=$i; next}
     {for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) print d[i], $i}
' input
```

you get

```
A|1
B|2
C|3
A|4
B|5
C|6
```

**Important Note**

your logic is correct, only `x[i]` instead of `x_i`

```
gawk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
NR==1{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
        x[i]=$i
    }
}
NR>1{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
        print x[i] FS $i
    }
}' input
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great. I have a similar question (see edit in my first post)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR==1{split($0,h);next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print h[i], $i}' file
A|1
B|2
C|3
A|4
B|5
C|6

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR==1{gsub(/\|/,";");h=$0;next} {print h, $0}' file
A;B;C|1|2|3
A;B;C|4|5|6
```

Read Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Great ! Thanks Ed

Answer (score 0):

Here is another using `split` and `for`:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 { split($0,a,"|") } 
       NR>1  { n=split($0,b,"|");
              for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                  print a[i] "|" b[i] }' file
A|1
B|2
C|3
A|4
B|5
C|6
```